# SQL Agent Failing Backup using Domain Account

Tags: sql-server, failovercluster

Good Day,

I am hoping you can help with a frustrating issue i have encountered.

We have recently setup a domain joined SQL 2022 Cluster using HYPER-V failover.

All is working well with the databases and the failover.

The issue We have encountered is with our SQL Agent jobs.

We have a few setup and when ever they are run we are presented this error.

> SSPI handshake failed with error code 0x8009030c, state 14 while
> establishing a connection with integrated security; the connection has
> been closed. Reason: AcceptSecurityContext failed. The operating
> system error code indicates the cause of failure. The logon attempt
> failed   [CLIENT: 192.168.36.217]
>
> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
> with Integrated authentication. [CLIENT: 192.168.36.217]

this error repeats 3 times.

The SQL cluster makes use of two ranges

192.168.30 for domain traffic

192.168.36 for SQL server traffic

Looking at the error above it appears the SQL agent job is attempting to authenticate to our DC but using the wrong IP range which has no access to our DC.
I have tried many fixes that are on multiple sites 
But they all appear to rather be for actually logging into SQL rather than the agent jobs.

Any help or advice to bypass this issue would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved by creating the DisableLoopbackCheck reg key
You can find it here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/accessing-server-locally-with-fqdn-cname-alias-denied
Method 2